# $x$ intercept problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

How would I find the $x$ intercept of $x^5-x^3+2=0$?  I haven’t learned about things like synthetic division or any theorems, just algebraic manipulations.

Comment: You must mean the $x$ intercept of $y=x^5-x^3+2$ which is the $x$ value that makes $y$ equal $0$.

Comment: Yes, I meant to include that

Comment: Where did this question come from?

Comment: Just a problem I found, I couldn’t seem to solve it, but that’s probably because I’m severely sleep deprived.

Comment: In general there is not a formulaic way of finding the roots of quintic( a polynomial of degree 5). This one doesn't seem likely to have a nice clean way of solving it.

Comment: [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E5-x%5E3%2B2%3D0) doesn't produce a nice form for this value which is close to: $-1.3478678959886521389$

Answer (score 1):

By the rational root theorem, if the function $f(x) = x^5 - x^3 + 2 = 0$ has a rational zero, then it must be among the rational numbers:

$1, -1, 2, -2$

However, we see that if we plug in any of these values of $x$ into our function, we will not get $0$. That is:

$f(1) = 2, \quad f(-1) = 2, \quad f(2) = 26, \quad f(-2) = -22$

Therefore, we may conclude that any value of $x$ which satisfies $x^5 - x^3 + 2 =0$ will not be a rational number (so, at best, we can only approximate the value of $x$ which does so). One of our options is to simply use a computer to approximate the solution for us. Otherwise, we would probably have to use Newton's Method to approximate this solution by hand (which is very tedious).

Comment: $x^4 + x^2 + 1$ has no rational roots but factors as two quadratics

Comment: Ah yes! I have corrected this mistake. Thank you for pointing this out

Answer (score 1):

My answer is not totally correct but I hope it helps  a little :

Consider $f(x)=x^5-x^3+2$  . we have $f'(x)=5x^4-3x^2$ and $f'(x)=0$ if $x=0$ or $x=\pm \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}$ and it is also possible to determine the sign of $f'(x)$ for all other $x$.

Note that $5x^4-3x^2>0$ if $5x^4>3x^2$ if $x^2>3/5$ . that is, $x >+ \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}$ or $x <- \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}$. Also $5x^4-3x^2<0$ if $- \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}<x<+ \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}$.

Thus $f$ is increasing for $x <- \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}$, decreasing between  $- \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}$ and $+ \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}$ and again increasing for $x>+ \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}$.

For this $f$, finding $x$ for $f(x)=0$ is difficult. But IVT guranteed that such a   number  is between $-2$ and $-1$, since $f(-2)<0$ and $f(-1)>0$

with this information the graph look like this:(with the help of Desmos) [image]

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=x^5-x^3+2\implies f'(x)=5x^4-3x^2\implies f''(x)=20x^3-6x$$

The first derivative cancels twice at $x=0$ and at $x=\pm \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}$.

$$f(0)=+2 $$
$$f\left(+\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}} \right)=2-\frac{6 \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}}{25}\approx 1.8141 \qquad f''\left(+\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}} \right)=6 \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}$$
$$f\left(-\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}} \right)=2+\frac{6 \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}}{25}\approx 2.1859 \qquad f''\left(-\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}} \right)=-6 \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}$$ So, ther is only one real root which is negative. By inspection, $f(-1)=2$, $f(-2)=-22$; so the root is close to $-1$.

To *approximate* the root, use Taylor series to get
$$f(x)=2+2 (x+1)-7 (x+1)^2+O\left((x+1)^3\right)$$ and the root to be considered is given by
$$x=\frac{1}{7} \left(\sqrt{15}-6\right)\approx -1.41043$$ Now, use Newton method which will update the guess according to
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}=\frac{-4 x_n^5+2 x_n^3+2}{3 x_n^2-5 x_n^4}$$ to get the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & -1.410426192 \\
 1 & -1.354288685 \\
 2 & -1.347943175 \\
 3 & -1.347867906 \\
 4 & -1.347867896
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for ten significant figures.